# Mandrill merge variables not working

Tags: mandrill

I'm using the following Python code to send Mandrill email:

```
    json_mandrill = dict(
        key=MANDRILL_KEY,
        template_name=template_name,
        template_content=[],
        global_merge_vars=[],
        message=dict(to=[dict(email=recipient)])
    )
    for name, content in merge_vars.items():
        json_mandrill["global_merge_vars"].append(
            dict(name=name, content=content))
    url = "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template.json"
    logging.info(json.dumps(json_mandrill))
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url,
        payload=json.dumps(json_mandrill),
        method=urlfetch.POST,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

Here is an example of the submitted JSON from my logs:

```
{"global_merge_vars": [{"content": 7, "name": "free_duration"}, {"content": 4615291308867584, "name": "eid"}, {"content": "poll", "name": "mode"}, {"content": "31 July 2015 at 09:44 EDT", "name": "exp"}, {"content": "Jeff", "name": "name"}], 
"template_content": [], 
"message": {"to": [{"email": REDACTED}]}, 
"key": REDACTED, 
"template_name": "manager-welcome"}
```

My Mandrill settings are set to use Handlebars and here is an excerpt from the template:

```
<p>Dear {{name}},</p>
```

And this is what appears in the received email:

```
<p>Dear ,</p>
```

The emails get sent, but the merge variables in the email are just blank.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looking at the submitted JSON, it looks like the "global_merge_vars" aren't nested properly. They should be nested in the "message" struct, instead of on the same level.

Comment: @terrorbox, Thank you!  That did the trick.  I feel silly for making that mistake.  Feel free to make your comment an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the submitted JSON, it looks like the "global_merge_vars" aren't nested properly. They should be nested in the "message" struct, instead of on the same level.